# How to configure/modify attribute value to the Active Directory user from command line?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008, active-directory-group

I am trying to automate the AD user attributes configuration.

I found "ADSI edit", "DSmod" options. But ADSI edit is a GUI tool and "DSmod" not allowing to modify all attributes.

Is there any command line tool to modify the below AD attributes for users:

```
1. department
2. employeeNumber
3. countrycode
4. Title
5. Description
```

Any help on this please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use powershell as your automation engine.  You can adjust any of the attributes easily. There is plenty of information about how to do that, you could start with this blog: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/21/use-the-powershell-ad-provider-to-modify-user-attributes.aspx or https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx